# Prototype iOS app with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, startup

I am developing a prototype iOS app to present it to investors.
The app uses Facebook login. My question is that should I use a platform like Firebase to save user profiles?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Firebase, yes, if it is not too time consuming and expensive (development wise) for the prototype.

Comment: What do you suggest to make it simpler?

Comment: I personally build my own server backends with user management.